# Access denied 403 when trying to download from the Google Cloud Platform, but user has all access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

We are just trying to use gsutil from the command line to download some DCM data from the Google Cloud Platform:

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://dcdt_-dcm_account75701/dcm_account75701_activity_201803* C:\Users\[omissis]\Desktop\ImprData
```

We are getting the error below, looks like an access issue, but we have made sure that all the correct access has been given in the cloud console.

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 [omissis] does not have storage.objects.list access to dcdt_-dcm_account75701. 
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred
```

Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: please don't screenshot text-only error msgs, cut&paste them, it makes it easier for others to find your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are copying multiple objects using a wildcard:

```
dcm_account75701_activity_201803*
```

For this to work, you need to grant your user also the storage.objects.list privilege, not just the storage.objects.get privilege.

To verify this is the case, replace `dcm_account75701_activity_201803*`
with the **full** name of one of the objects in the `dcdt_-dcm_account75701` bucket.

EDIT: notice that `storage.buckets.list` and `storage.objects.list` are two distinct privileges. The former allows you to list all buckets belonging to your project, the latter (which you are missing) allows you to list the objects inside the bucket.

According to the user guide:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

being an Owner grants you the storage.buckets.* privileges, not the storage.objects.* privileges.
You might want to grant the storage.objectAdmin role to your user.

Comment: Cheers Luca, I have checked and I have access to that list. I have the same access as other people who don't get this error.

Comment: are the others also using wildcards in the source filename?

Comment: Yea we're all using the same command prompt

Comment: what error msg do you get if you use the full name of an object instead of the wildcard?

Comment: How do we get to a list of the objects?

Comment: gsutil ls gs://bucket

Comment: we have tried this, still says access denied. We have made sure our permissions are "owner" level

Comment: answer updated with details on owner level

Comment: @Matt did you try granting the storage.objectAdmin role?

Comment: We have granted the storage.objectAdmin role and still cant get it to work im afraid. Other users with just owner access are able to run the command.